# Graceful degradation of AJAX in flask

Tags: ajax, rest, flask

I'm building an application in flask using RESTful http methods. I have a page with two forms on it, one which allows a user to create an object (one form one button), and another which lists existing objects and allows the user to delete and modify them (one form, two buttons).

I've set up an AJAX system to handle these forms. Depending on the action (create, update, delete), I send requests to the server with different headers (POST, PUT, DELETE). On the flask side, I have a `MethodView` with the appropriate methods to handle these requests.

My problem is users without javascript enabled. By default, the form has a `POST` action - however, my `MethodView` is written to handle `POST` as creating a new object, so it won't be able to handle the input of the whole form. In addition, both my forms have `POST` as their default action, so as it is now they would both be handled by the same function that does not differentiate between them.

How can I support both AJAX and regular form submission in my view?

Here's my update/delete form:

```
<form method="POST" role="form" id="process-form">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="process-selection-0" name="process-selection" type="checkbox" value="1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="process-selection-0">
                            <a href="/projects/1">
                            aaa
                        </a>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <h3>Selected file actions:</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="process-process_button" name="action" type="submit" value="0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks "></span> Process</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="process-delete_button" name="action" type="submit" value="-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span> Delete</button>
</form>
```

And here's my update/delete AJAX javascript:

```
$('form#process-form > #process-process_button').click(function (event) {

    var formData = $( '#process-form' ).serialize()
    console.log("Sending data:")
    console.log(formData)
    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type         : 'PUT', 
        url          : '/projects/',
        data         : formData,
        dataType     : 'json',
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data); 
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('form#process-form > #process-delete_button').click(function (event) {

    var formData = $( '#process-form' ).serialize()
    console.log("Sending data:")
    console.log(formData)
    $.ajax({
        type         : 'DELETE',
        url         : '/projects/',
        data         : formData,
        dataType     : 'json',
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data); 
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: try this for update form `<form action="your_end_url" method="PUT">` you can specify method attribute value depends upon your need

Comment: My update and delete forms are one form with two buttons. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: how you are submitting your form using **jqeury.ajax**??, can u add that code?

Comment: Sure, added to the op.

Comment: every thing looks good, can u please remove method="POST" in your form and try now??

Comment: Ah, when I remove that the form submits as GET and passes the fields as url arguments that I can use in flask. Is it acceptable for a GET request to change data on the server?

Comment: i think it submitting form try **type="button"** in your process, delete buttons

Comment: Then the form won't submit at all...

Comment: You have click actions right that should submit

Comment: What if a user has javascript disabled? That's what I'm concerned about.